# HTML Form unrespoinsive in Certain Design

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a simple HTML-form for my spreadsheet that lets me input some data and use that data to do stuff in the script. Now i let someone do a few design-tweaks to the HTML file and now for some reason it does not seem to work anymore(the button is unresponsive/does not call the function). First version does work, second does not.

1. How do i troubleshoot best what is going wrong in the HTML file.
2. Is there any obvious mistake with the code:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>
> <head>
>   <base target="_top">
> </head>
> <br>
> <script>
>     function myFunction()
>     {
>        var date = new Date();
>        document.getElementById('date').placeholder = date.toLocaleDateString();
>     }
> </script>
> <body onload= "myFunction()">
>   <div align="center">
>       <form>
>           Project Name
>           <font color=red>*</font>:<br>
>           <input type="text" name="pName">
>             <br>
>           <br> Project Owner
>           <font color=red>*</font>:<br>
>           <input type="text" name="pOwner">
>             <br>
>           <br> Sheet Responsible:<br>
>           <input type="text" name="pResp">
>             <br>
>           <br> Starting Time:<br>
>           <input type="text" name="pDate" id="date">
>             <br>
>           <br><br>
>           <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="google.script.run
>                 .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
>                 .createSheet(this.parentNode)" />
>       </form>
>   </div>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html>
> <style>
>     div {
>         margin: auto;
>         width: 40%;
>         font-family: Arial;
>     }
>     div.button {
>         text-align: center;
>     }
>     input[type=text] {
>         width: 100%;
>     }
> </style>
> <script>
>     function myFunction()
>     {
>        var date = new Date();
>        document.getElementById('date').placeholder = date.toLocaleDateString();
>     }
> </script>
> <head>
>    <base target="_top">
> </head>
> <br>
>
> <body onload="myFunction()">
>    <div>
>       <form>
>             Project Name
>             <font color=red>*</font>:<br>
>             <input type="text" name="pName">
>             <br>
>             <br>Project Owner
>             <font color=red>*</font>:<br>
>             <input type="text" name="pOwner">
>             <br>
>             <br>Sheet Responsible:<br>
>             <input type="text" name="pResp">
>             <br>
>             <br>Starting Time:<br>
>             <input type="text" name="pDate" id="date">
>             <br>
>             <br>
>          <div class="button">
>             <br>
>             <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="google.script.run
>                 .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
>                 .createSheet(this.parentNode)" />
>          </div>
>       </form>
>    </div>
>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Try `.createSheet(this.parentNode.parentNode)`   Add a second `parentNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what happens:

— You've wrapped your button into another `div` to control its style but at the same time you've changed its parent node.

— When your button wasn't wrapped in that `div`, `form` would be the parent node and `this.parentNode` would return an object with empty properties:

```
console.log("parent node is %s", JSON.stringify(element)); ==>
parent node is {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{}}
```

— After wrapping, the same entity is completely empty:

```
console.log("parent node is %s", JSON.stringify(element)); ==>
parent node is {}
```

— And your function doesn't want to take it as an argument, it all just doesn't go to the server side (where it would probably crash, too).

---

What can you do to make it work again without removing that `div`? Probably, figure out what else can be passed into your `createSheet()` function.

What could you do to find the errors by yourself? Probably, create another client side function of this kind:

```
function newFunction(element) {
   console.log("parent node is %s", JSON.stringify(element));
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).createSheet(element);
}
```

So your click handler would change to `onclick="newFunction(this.parentNode)"`

This additional function would allow you to track what's going on in your code through console (or in some other way) more easily than when using inline events assignment.